# Sums of powers of $5$ - general term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence is:

$1,5,6,25,26,30,31,125,126,130,131,150,151,155...$

(All the numbers that can be written as a sum of different powers of $5$.)

What is formula for the general term of this sequence?

Comment: Do you mean: "The coefficients of $5^p$ " ?

Comment: You can have a recursive formula: $a_0=0, a_n=5a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}+(n\pmod 2)$

Comment: The sequence contains exactly the positive integers having only digits $0$ and $1$  in the expansion in base $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a closed form, but the $n$ th term can be determined by converting $n$ in a binary expansion and interprete this digit sequence in base $5$.

Comment: The series [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C6%2C25%2C26%2C30%2C31%2C125%2C126%2C130%2C131%2C150%2C151%2C155&sort=&language=&go=Search) describes the formula as 1/4 of another but the other describes itself as 4 times this one.